# access underlying entity in symfony2 form builder

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm looking for a way to access the data class entity in a symfony2 form builder class.

The reason I need this is because the text on the submit button should change depending on a value of this entity (a value the user cannot change in the form).

so basically I want to do:

```
if ($this->entity->getVariable() == xxx) {
// do something
} else {
// do something else
}
```

inside the form builder class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

praxmatig pointed me in the right direction, the solution is even easier:

the underlying entity is automatically available as an option named "data", so you can do:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
   // whatever

   if (isset($options['data'])) {
      switch ($options['data']->getSomeVariable()) {
      // whatever
      }
   }

   // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create the form from controller, you can pass anything you want as the options

```
// AcmeType.php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $entity = $options['entity'];
}

// AcmeController.php
$form = $this->createForm(new AcmeType(), $entity, array('entity' => $entity));
```

Or a better but harder way to do this is using the [form event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-underlying-data)